# Why does React.isValidElement(this.ref.current) return false

Tags: reactjs

I don't understand the why React.isValidElement(ref.current) returns false. Isn't true the correct value?

```
class Input extends React.Component {
  render() { return <input {...this.props} />; }
}
const CounterDisplay = (props) => {
  const inputEl = useRef(null);

  const handleChange = () => {
    console.log(React.isValidElement(<Input />)); // true
    console.log(React.isValidElement(inputEl.current)); // false
  }

  return <div>
    <Input ref={inputEl} onChange={handleChange} />
  </div>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `inputEl.current` is a ref. And `isValidElement` returns true if what you pass is a valid element. An element is described as

> React elements are the building blocks of React applications. One might confuse elements with a more widely known concept of “components”. An element describes what you want to see on the screen. React elements are immutable.

[Source](https://reactjs.org/docs/glossary.html#elements)

Also, since react is open source, you can directly see the [code](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/745baf2e061bdb7a07b511fa6fd8c1c5e8106313/packages/react/src/ReactElement.js#L499) if you need.

```
export function isValidElement(object) {
  return (
    typeof object === 'object' &&
    object !== null &&
    object.$$typeof === REACT_ELEMENT_TYPE
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I already know the different between react element and react component. I think the react element is the instance of react component. And the ref can get the instance of component.  
Like [React Document](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) says: 
       Refs provide a way to access DOM nodes or React elements created in the 
       render method.

Comment: Good. Then, please scroll a little further on that document to see what a ref actually is: [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#accessing-refs).